# Attach debugger for native code via command line

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, lldb

I want to debug C++ code in [Firefox for Android](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/mobile/android/fenix.html) and got things working with Android Studio following the guide ["Debugging Native Code in Android Studio"](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/mobile/android/geckoview/contributor/native-debugging.html#debugging-native-code-in-android-studio) from the Firefox Docs.

While this is already useful, I would like to do this from VSCode and therefore from command line. The reason being that I don't have 'smart' code navigation, code completion etc. for C++ code in Android Studio, but I do have that for VSCode. Another reason would be, that having this from command line would open things up for other people to set up proper C++ debugging from their editor or IDE of choice.

There's an [interesting section](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/mobile/android/geckoview/contributor/native-debugging.html#attaching-debuggers-to-content-and-other-child-processes) in the Firefox Docs that touches upon that. I need to attach the debugger to a child process. The docs show how to set the debug app to be the child process and to wait for a debugger to attach. What I'm lacking now is how exactly to attach the debugger (in my case LLDB, I'm on macOS btw.) via command line to that child process. Would anybody be able to help me with that or know where to look for information?

I *think*, after getting things running from command line, I should then be able to create the respective [`launch.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) file entries for VSCode in order to have the debugging working. What do you think?

Comment: This page has some discussion of using lldb for remote debugging, including Android: https://lldb.llvm.org/use/remote.html

Comment: This looks really interesting, I will work through it. Thank you!